# expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (15936, 64)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Hello I'm new to Deep Learning and Keras and I was doing a project in order to learn Deep Learning and Keras. Here I've made a model.

```
Model = Sequential()
Model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3) , input_shape = (100,64,64,), padding = 'same', 
activation='relu'))
Model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
Model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) 
Model.add(Flatten()) #Conversion to Neurons
Model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu')) 
Model.add(Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

For training and  fitting.

```
X = signalBuffer.transpose()
Y = np.ones([19920, 1], dtype = int)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, 
test_size=0.20,shuffle=True)
Model.fit(x_train, y_train,batch_size=100,epochs=epochs,validation_data= 
(x_test, y_test),shuffle=True)
```

Here the X has 19920 rows and 64 columns and Y has 19920 rows and 1 column.
The training and testing splitting is executing without errors. The error is coming in the last line when I try to fit in the model.
The error is

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (15936, 64)

Pardon me if this is a silly question or answer is very easy, but I'm trying to understand the model and I've tried a few solutions but its still giving errors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/):

> 2D convolution layer (e.g. spatial convolution over images).
>
> This layer creates a convolution kernel that is convolved with the layer input to produce a tensor of outputs. If  use_bias is True, a bias vector is created and added to the outputs. Finally, if activation is not None, it is applied to the outputs as well.
>
> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide the keyword argument input_shape (tuple of integers, does not include the sample axis), e.g. input_shape=(128, 128, 3) for 128x128 RGB pictures in  data_format="channels_last".

What you have is 19920 samples and 64 features, assuming that this is correct, you should probably go for a 1D convolutional layer instead. The 1D convolutional layer takes a 2D input, it is the kernel itself that is 1D

you will probably need to do some changes to ensure that your data is in the correct format as well, as the Conv1D takes the following:

> Input shape
> 3D tensor with shape: (batch, steps, channels)

Comment: I understood batch, but can you give some insights on steps and channels. Like for example in Conv2D I was giving 32 filters of 3X3 each then I gave the size of input and then activation so here what are steps and channels and where should I give activation and filters. I only had idea about 2D Convolutions, I've never tried 1D.

Comment: "Channels" is equivalent to your samples while "Steps" is equivalent to your features, i.e you have 19920 channels and 64 steps

Answer (score 0):

Convolutions are used to exploit the fact that spatial locality matters, e.g. near pixel are important to each other to find edges or classify something. This is seldomn the case with tabular data. If you still want to use NN to solve this you might want to use MLPs, e.g. dense layer for your task. Then you do not have to do anything apart from removing the convolutional part.

If your data is spatially connected then you might want to use Conv1D layers. As a previos post explains the input shape is a 3D tensor with (Batch, steps, channels). The amount of parameters create is dependant on the number of input channels and number of output channels and irrelevant of the step parameter. E.g. reshaping your data to be (19920, 1, 64) will produce a dense layer. The other extreme is (19920, 64, 1) where the amount of parameters is solely dependand on kernel size and outgoing channel maps.